# How to use Python tornado's run_sync while creating async subroutines?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I'd like to run a method with tornado IOLoop's run_sync that starts asynchronous methods.

Here's the idea:

```
@gen.coroutine
def async(string):
    print string


@gen.coroutine
def sync():
    string_list = yield async_call()
    for string in string_list:
        async(string=string)

loop = IOLoop.current()
loop.run_sync(lambda: sync)
```

So, everything in sync needs to occur synchronously but the order in which async is called does not matter. Is this possible with tornado?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you misunderstood the meaning of asyncronous computing. In a nutshell if you have two functions that you execute asyncronously in IOLoop, the code of each function will be executed simultaneously but the workflow of function will be still syncronous.

When you run `async` method without `yield` keyword you are to be shure that it finishes before the caller function, especially when you use `run_sync` which stops IOLoop after function stopped. This can cause undefined behavior when `async` is still running but IOLoop is stopped.

I've edited your code to show that `sync`'s function workflow is executed synchronously:

```
@gen.coroutine
def async(string):
    yield gen.sleep(2)
    print string

@gen.coroutine
def async_call():
    return ["one", "two", "three"]

@coroutine
def sync():
    string_list = yield async_call()
    for string in string_list:
        yield async(string)

loop = IOLoop.current()
loop.run_sync(sync)
```

The output:

```
$python test_async.py
one
two
three
```

Comment: almost, invoking async actually schedule and execute the function, unless ioloop will be stopped. Async functions require ioloop to run, yielded or not. With `yield` it waits until async finish.

Comment: @kwarunek Thanks for you mention, i've checked this in at my machine and it seems to run as you say. But there is one thing that isn't still clear for me: in case when `async` method requires more time to finish than `sync` IOLoop will be stoped before it ends and i don't really imagine will `async` complete correctly or not.